# A bash script to show logged off users

Tags: bash, scripts

Please help me create a bash script to show logged off users.

It's easy to know which users are logged into a PC, the problem is to see those who are not, I have some time looking online, without results.

Comment: *Logged off*? O.o That's pretty useless - unless you specify some criteria to exclude a good section of them (say, no system users, for example).

Comment: You may find the `last` command useful: `man last`; and possibly also `man wtmp`

Comment: Thank you very much!!, Yes I know it is useless-_-, but is for a exercise for the university

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about homework.

Comment: I like it more “academic reasons” In the end the important thing is to share knowledge., I  been looking for ideas in the internet, but I don't found nothing.

Comment: To ask about homework is fine, as long as you share you thoughts and, what you tried so far and with which results. Just dumping the question here is off-topic, because it's not about Ubuntu, but only your homework. Since this is a general Unix problem I would recommend to ask on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Using `comm`, `awk`, `users` and `/etc/passwd`

```
comm -23 <(awk -F: '/\/home/ && ($3 >= 1000) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort ) <(users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq)
```

---

*Breakdown*

```
% awk -F: '/\/home/ && ($3 >= 1000) {print $1}' /etc/passwd
user1
user2

% users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq
user1

% comm -23 <(awk -F: '/\/home/ && ($3 >= 1000) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort ) <(users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq)
user2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!, I had tried a few options without good results, at the end a string it was logical.

Comment: @user3567021 As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: That works as advertised. Bravo!